# Wheel advice/information

Tags: wheels

I just bought a Top Fuel 9, 2016, 27.5. It came with Bontrager Mustang Pro wheels.  Where would I find the specs for these wheels?  I am thinking of upgrading the wheel set.  Any suggestions for upgraded wheels?

Comment: Looks like Trek has pulled out the info about the wheelset from their site. I've managed to find a [store](http://www.tritoncycles.co.uk/components-c9/wheels-c126/bontrager-mustang-pro-27-5-wheel-p14529) that sells them: not much technical details, but maybe helpful for resell pricing. You could measure inner width with calipers at least. As for suggestions, we don't do product recommendations here. All I'd say there are certainly more expensive and lighter wheels out there available as upgrade.

Comment: We recommend round wheels as the best sort.  If you want to spend extra, get the ones with rubber tyres too.

Comment: Thank you @Klaster!  That is the info I was looking for!

Comment: Most wheels have a decal on the rim giving the rim manufacturer, the nominal size of the rim, and maybe a model/style name.  And the hub generally has the manufacturer's name and maybe a model name engraved on it.  You can count the spokes, and determine if they are radial or "laced".  And it should be obvious whether the wheel is for rim or disk brakes.  You don't need any more info than that.

Comment: Well, hub width and casssette compatibility are important too. And if its a disc wheel, what kind of disc mount it has.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only thing you need to know besides diameter (27.5 duh), freehub body type (standard shimano style or SRAM XD) and rotor mount (6 bolt or center-loc) is rather or not the hubs are "Boost" spec (110 front & 148 rear) or standard thru-axle (100 front & 142 rear).
Of course don't do something silly like buy super wide (30mm internal width or wider) rims and your all set to shred that gnar...

Comment: The OP specifically asked about upgrade, he needs to know a lot more information than just finding a wheel that fits or it could end up being a downgrade or sideways shift.